# Error direclty opening activity with Camera API SurfaceView from MainActivity

Tags: android, camera

I have a MainActivity which is only used if phone number is not set in Shared Preference. After setting phone number once there is no need of MainActivity and everytime user opens app he should goto CameraActivity Activity which have Camera API working in SurfaceView in it.

There is no problem in opening CameraActivity using button on MainActivity but if I open CameraActivity from MainACtivity onCreate method then I am facing following Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera.setDisplayOrientation(int)' on a null object reference
            at com.vivertechnologies.camera.ShowCamera.refreshCamera(ShowCamera.java:208)
            at com.vivertechnologies.camera.ShowCamera.surfaceChanged(ShowCamera.java:281)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:590)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:176)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1983)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1081)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5818)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5234)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

My Code from Camera API is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_show);

        Thread t = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // update TextView here!
                                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                                String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
                                TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateTime);
                                txtView.setText(formattedDate);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };

        t.start();

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                new Thread(new SavePicThread(data)).start();
//
//                Intent i = new Intent(ShowCamera.this, UploadActivity.class);
//                i.putExtra("isImage", data);
//                startActivity(i);
                refreshCamera();
            }
        };
    }
```

Refresh Camera Method which is generating error:

```
public void refreshCamera() {
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }
        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        int rotation = ((WindowManager)ShowCamera.this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;

        // specifically for back facing camera
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
        }


        camera.setDisplayOrientation(degrees);
        setCamera(camera);
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("AAAAA", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I am unable to identify how it can be solved.

**Edit:**

Complete Code:

```
    package com.vivertechnologies.camera;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by usman on 27/11/15.
 */
public class ShowCamera extends MainActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    Camera.PictureCallback rawCallback;
    Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
    Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback;


    private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private Context mContext;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private final String TAG = "CameraSurfaceView";
    private Camera mCamera;
    private List<String> mSupportedFlashModes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_show);

        Thread t = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // update TextView here!
                                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                                String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
                                TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateTime);
                                txtView.setText(formattedDate);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };

        t.start();

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                new Thread(new SavePicThread(data)).start();
//
//                Intent i = new Intent(ShowCamera.this, UploadActivity.class);
//                i.putExtra("isImage", data);
//                startActivity(i);
                refreshCamera();
            }
        };
    }

    private void galleryAddPic(File file) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        ShowCamera.this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }


    public class SavePicThread implements Runnable {
        byte[] data;
        public SavePicThread(byte[] data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
        public void run() {
            // make a new picture file
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();

            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                // write to the file
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                ShowCamera.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
//                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ShowCamera.this, "Picture saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
//                        toast.show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // make the picture visible to the rest of the device
            galleryAddPic(pictureFile);
            Intent i = new Intent(ShowCamera.this, UploadActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("filePath", pictureFile.getPath());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    // make picture and save to a folder
    private File getOutputMediaFile() {
        // make a new file directory inside the "sdcard" folder
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "imgCaptureApp");

        // if the directory does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            // if you cannot make this directory return
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        // take the current timeStamp
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        // and make a media file:
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }



    public void captureImage(View v) throws IOException {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
    }

    public void refreshCamera() {
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }
        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        int rotation = ((WindowManager)ShowCamera.this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;

        // specifically for back facing camera
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
        }


        camera.setDisplayOrientation(degrees);
        setCamera(camera);
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("AAAAA", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera)
    {
        Camera mCamera = camera;
        if (mCamera != null)
        {
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            mSupportedFlashModes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes();
            // Set the camera to Auto Flash mode.
            if (mSupportedFlashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO))
            {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            }
        }
        surfaceView.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
        }

        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }

        Camera.Parameters param;
        param = camera.getParameters();

        List<Camera.Size> sizes = param.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
        for(int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++)
        {
            if(sizes.get(i).width > size.width)
                size = sizes.get(i);
        }
        param.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
        param.setRotation(90);
        param.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
//        param.setPreviewSize(352, 288);
        camera.setParameters(param);

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        refreshCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: where it's defined camera?

Comment: at the starting of class Camera camera;

Comment: ok, you have to call Camera camera = new Camera(); before call refreshCamera(), because camera is null object on refreshCamera() method

Comment: not working. When I add it in code Studio show red line under it. I think there is no need of creating object at this time. Because code is working fine if I come to CameraActivity on button click

Comment: post cameraActivity and Camera code

Comment: check updated question

Comment: camera object NEED to be instantiated before do all operation..

Comment: where to instantiate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, your problem appears to be that `ShowCamera` is a subclass of `MainActivity`. Presumably, you have something similar to the following in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` method:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = ...

if(prefs.getBoolean("phone_number_set", false)) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, ShowCamera.class));
}
```

Since `ShowCamera` is a subclass of `MainActivity`, calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in `ShowCamera`'s `onCreate()` method is executing `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` method again. When you open `ShowCamera` with the `Button`, you've not yet set the phone number, so the `if` conditional shown above is `false`, and the `startActivity()` method doesn't get called again.

However, after you've set the phone number, the conditional is `true`, and it starts `ShowCamera` again, which is calling `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()`, which executes the `if` block, which starts `ShowCamera`, which calls `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()`, which executes the `if` block, which starts `ShowCamera`... This is easily verified by adding a `static int` to the `ShowCamera` class, printing it to the Log in `onCreate()`, and then immediately incrementing it.

Eventually, one of the `ShowCamera` instances will layout its `SurfaceView` and call `refreshCamera()` from the `surfaceChanged()` callback, but it will have a null `Camera` object, because a previous Activity already has the camera.open, and it will throw the `NullPointerException` you're getting.

The solution is simple. Change the  `ShowCamera` class to be a direct subclass of `Activity`. That is:

```
public class ShowCamera extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot :) . Bounty need 7 hours to be awarded.